# Jest runs 40 times slower than mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, mocha.js

I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9653), but it got closed immediately without any information if this is normal and acceptable;

I'll post the question here.

---

Thinking that this is normal could be one of the biggest mistakes of my career so far. I was tinkering with CodeSandbox and noticed how instantaneous the tests were compared to what I was used to. Set up a basic template project, and here are my results:

```
{
  "name": "jest-performance-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^23.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

`jest.config.js`

```
{
  "testRegex": "__tests__/*",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
}
```

Several dozen duplicated tests with

```
const {expect} = require('chai')

it ('should run the test', async () => {
  expect (true).to.be.true
})

//...
```

in each

running `jest --watch`, making a change and saving:

[image: jest results]

running `yarn run test --watch` (`mocha --watch`), making a change and saving:

[image]

`--runInBand` makes it even worse.

I get it, I'm stuck with 5y/o Windows laptop on HDD and all that, but *40 times*?

I have projects with pretty intricate jest setups, and tried to solve the issue of performance many times over the last year or so.

Is there *anything* I can do to not switch to mocha/chai? I don't feel like running a single jest test anymore.

Comment: I'm currently setting it up mocha to work with typescript, and so far it's not very fast - 

_it's freaking instantaneous_. I press save, raise my eyes up and it has already passed the test. I can't believe it.

Comment: Comparing lot of tests is not most reliable. It would be more practical to run single test. It would be easier to investigate. Also your ts+jest setup is probably not optimal. Did You tried to search for working solution?

Comment: also upgrading jest to newest could also help.

Comment: @SkorpEN I have run test with plain JS, so that's out of the question. Jest is up to date.
Long story short, all alternative solutions simply suck haha. I've played around with settings, --maxWorkers and whatnot and seem to have arrived at somewhat satisfactory performance. I suppose having all the tools bundled-in is worth extra overhead, especially considering that I'll upgrade to better HW eventually.

Comment: Hi I am trying to evaluate a test framework / runner for my vue js projects and came across this article https://medium.com/dailyjs/javascript-test-runners-benchmark-3a78d4117b4. any suggestions since you have been using this?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your test repo?

Comment: One strategy that might help is generating a flame graph (for example with 0x).  I have a different problem — optimizing some mocha tests — but I was able to see where mocha was spending its time and optimize somewhat

Answer (score 7):

I use both in my projects, and yes, the performance difference is very real.

I use `jest` only when it offers enhanced support for front-end modules - it is very good for React for example. Otherwise I always use `mocha`.

`jest` uses Babel to transpile all TypeScript code - including `node_modules` when they need to be transpiled - to JavaScript.
`mocha` uses `ts-node` to directly run TypeScript.

This is the reason for the difference.